# Batch loop through file

Tags: batch-file, notepad++

I'm trying to make a batch process in Notepad++ that will count the number of duplicate lines from text selected.

So far I have Notepad++ working fine

```
NPE_CONSOLE v+
CLS
ECHO $(CURRENT_WORD)
CON_SAVETO "H:\tmp.txt"
NPE_CONSOLE v-
```

This scripts saves the selected text into `tmp.txt` with the only issue being it includes, at the bottom, `CON_SAVETO "H:\tmp.txt"` but I can live with that for now.

**EDIT**: Also, I do not think Notepad++ is the issue here since I try running the batch file from `cmd` line and get the same errors/problems.  I also tried setting the `tmp.txt` file manually and still same issues.

My batch file is what is causing issues:

```
::@ECHO OFF
CD "H:\"
SET counter=0
SET prev=a

FOR /F "tokens=*" %%L IN (tmp.txt) DO (
    SET blnOut=0
    SET curLine="%%L"

    IF /I %prev%==%curLine% (
        SET counter=%counter%+1
        SET blnOut=1
    )
    IF %blnOut%==0 (
        IF %prev%==a (
            SET counter=%counter%+1
            SET blnOut=1
        )
        IF %blnOut%==0 (
            ECHO %curLine%- %counter%
            SET counter=1
        )
    )
    SET prev=%curLine%
)
```

I've tried everything I can think of, including splitting off the process into a function, but I keep getting errors like `Unexpected )` or, if it does run, it does not loop through the file.

Currently, this is `tmp.txt`:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
1
4
5
8
4
3
4
4
5
```

So Ideal output is:

```
1 - 2
2 - 1
3 - 2
4 - 5
5 - 3
6 - 1
7 - 1
8 - 2
```

Comment: Do you think notepad++ causes this behaviour?

Comment: I do not think Notepad++ is the problem here, though I included the code in case someone can confirm or deny that.  Updated question to better explain that.

Comment: How do you call your batch file (and what parameters do you pass in); i.e. what does `%1` resolve to in this example?

Comment: My bad, `%1` was left in from when I tried it as a separate function.  There are no parameters passed to this and it is called by simply using the full path (`"H:\scripts\UniqueLine.bat"`)

Comment: Is using a batch file a requirement here? Or can it be any type of script? As you have it written, it looks like the logic will only find _consecutive_ lines that are the same; not lines that are duplicated elsewhere. Doing this kind of thing in batch (which is a terrible programming language, by the way) is going to be very difficult. It would be trivial with something like Perl.

Comment: I'm not sure how that would work with Notepad++ so I'd need to look into that before disregarding the .bat option.  I do have a way to sort the data prior to saving though so that is not much of a problem for me but you are correct.

Comment: I think what you want is the [EnableDelayedExpansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) option. Loops don't work like you think they might in batch files (like I say, it's a _terrible_ language). Also, don't forget the `/D` option to your `CD` command; `CD` will not automatically change drives without it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL enabledelayedexpansion
FOR %%i IN (prev) DO SET "%%i="
FOR /f "delims=" %%i IN ('sort ^<temp.txt') DO (
 IF DEFINED prev (
  IF "!prev!"=="%%i" (SET /a count+=1) ELSE (
  ECHO !prev! - !count!
  SET "prev="
  )
 )
 IF NOT DEFINED prev (
  SET prev=%%i
  SET /a count=1
 )
)
ECHO %prev% - %count%
```

Here's my version. Sort the input file to group like lines together, then when the line-contents change, display the previous contents and count and reset the counter and record of previous line.

Comment: +1 Great idea using `sort`.  This is more efficient than [my solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15842198/1683264) I think.  It won't keep the lines in order though.  Not sure whether that's important.

Comment: Love it when it is nearly copy-paste solution. (had to change `temp` to `tmp` and re-insert the `CD`) but fantastic.  Works like magic.

Comment: @DavidStarkey - There are potential problems with this answer: It works fine with numbers, but it can fail with alpha and symbols for two reasons: 1) SORT is case insensitive. If you don't care about case, then use `IF /I "!prev!"=="%%i"` to get the correct case insensitive answer. 2) The delayed expansion will corrupt value of `%%i` if it contains `!`. This can be solved by toggling delayed expansion on and off, taking care to preserve values across the ENDLOCAL barrier as needed.

Answer (score 3):

The Batch program below do what you want in a faster way, as long as the lines does not contain certain special Batch characters:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for /F "delims=" %%a in (tmp.txt) do (
   set /A "line[%%a]+=1"
)
for /F "tokens=2* delims=[]=" %%a in ('set line[') do (
   echo %%a - %%b
)
```

Comment: I thought about this, but any line containing []= will cause unexpected results.  Since this is intended to be used with a macro for Notepad++ it stands to reason that there will be programming symbols in the selected text he's checking for duplicate lines.  +1 for great minds think alike, though.

Comment: I just made a minor fix that allows any contents in the line, excepting special Batch characters like exclamation-mark

Answer (score 3):

I have a different but easier solution for you.

You can download [GNU utilities for win32](http://sourceforge.net/projects/unxutils/?source=dlp). Then just extract it. It is a collection of ported tools for Windows. Very handy.

Then use the the `sort` and `uniq` programs from there. You can find them in

```
extracted_folder\usr\local\wbin\
```

then you can just simply do

```
sort original_file.txt | uniq --count > count.txt
```

from windows `command line`. You will find what you need in `count.txt`

---

Make sure you have the paths correct OR you have the extracted folder in your `path`. If not in path then do something like

```
"C:\GNUWin_standalone\usr\local\wbin\sort.exe" original_file.txt | "C:\GNUWin_standalone\usr\local\wbin\uniq.exe" --count > count.txt
```

Comment: +1 Of the 6 answers posted so far, this is the most efficient, and the only one where it shouldn't matter whether any special characters exist in the checked content.  unixutils and gnuwin32 make Windows scripting so much easier.

Comment: +1, I'm impressed that you recognize that you must use the GNU `sort` utility, and not the native Windows `sort` utility. The stupid Windows `sort` is case insensitive :-(

Answer (score 2):

You can't set an environment variable and use it within the same `for` loop using `%` syntax, you need to use delayed expansion and use `!` syntax.

I haven't tested this, but try this:

```
::@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
CD "H:\"
SET counter=0
SET prev=a

FOR /F "tokens=*" %%L IN (tmp.txt) DO (
    SET blnOut=0
    SET curLine="%%L"

    IF /I !prev!==!curLine! (
        SET counter=!counter!+1
        SET blnOut=1
    )
    IF !blnOut!==0 (
        IF !prev!==a (
            SET counter=!counter!+1
            SET blnOut=1
        )
        IF !blnOut!==0 (
            ECHO !curLine!- !counter!
            SET counter=1
        )
    )
    SET prev=!curLine!
)
```

Or move the body of the `for` loop into a subroutine.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my idea for a little different direction.  It outputs the results you expect.  Output is not sorted; the original order of lines is maintained.

```
@ECHO OFF
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set filename=h:\tmp.txt
set idx=0

:: build array of unique lines
FOR /F "usebackq delims=" %%I IN ("%filename%") DO (

    rem :: if dupe line not already processed
    2>NUL set line | findstr /r /c:"^line\[[0-9]*\]=%%I$" >NUL || (

        rem :: add it to the array
        set "line[!idx!]=%%I"
        set /a "idx+=1"
    )
)

:: For each unique line
set /a "idx-=1"
for /L %%I in (0,1,%idx%) do (

    rem :: Echo the line contents without a line break
    set /p "=!line[%%I]! - "<NUL

    rem :: use find /c to count the instances of that line.
    findstr /b /e /c:"!line[%%I]!" "%filename%" | find /c "!line[%%I]!"
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You made more errors, I would tell now. Look at `delayed expansion`, `if /?`, `for /?`, `set /?` and all the batch stuff ...

```
@ECHO OFF &setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
CD /d "H:\"
SET counter=0
SET prev=a

FOR /F "tokens=*" %%L IN (tmp.txt) DO (
    SET blnOut=0
    SET "curLine=%%L"

    IF /I "!prev!"=="!curLine!" (
        SET /a counter+=1
        SET blnOut=1
    )
    IF "!blnOut!"=="0" (
        IF "!prev!"=="a" (
            SET /a counter+=1
            SET blnOut=1
        )
        IF "!lnOut!"=="0" (
            ECHO !curLine!- !counter!
            SET counter=1
        )
    )
    SET "prev=!curLine!"
)
```

Your code makes no sense, if you postet the content of `tmp.txt`correctly.

Comment: "Your code makes no sense, if you postet the content of `tmp.txt` correctly."  This comment is unhelpful as it does not explain what is wrong nor why it is wrong.

Comment: Sorry, but your knowledge in batch is so poor & life is short.